# SID to WAV converter that exports per channel separately

Tags: commodore-64, software, sound, sid

For a C64 SID project of mine (https://soundcloud.com/c64er) I was using an converter almost 10 years ago, but it is missing now with its name... I researched many sites, but no lucky. Is there any SID to WAV converter that exports every channel separately?

Comment: What was the name of the converter?

Comment: @bjb Totally forgotten :(

Comment: I would try to locate some function calls of the lib you're missing in a source code of yours and then search the web by those function names ...

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about built-in support for rendering per-track wave files automatically, but you could write a batch file or shell script to drive a command-line SID-to-Wave tool to play it multiple times, leaving a different channel un-muted each time.

[JSIDPlay2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsidplay2/) can be used that way.

- ✓ Works on all major platforms
- ✓ Supports your choice of cycle-accurate emulation or hardware SID cards
- ✓ Can be run in a shell script or batch file via the `--audio WAV`, `--muteVoice1`, `--muteVoice2`, etc. options
- ✓ According to [this thread](https://www.lemon64.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45631&sid=50de7d4748263925e9a1e6312acf36f3), filtering support isn't contingent on having all channels un-muted like with SidAmp.
- ✗ Unless you have a powerful machine, you may find it takes more than 3 minutes to render a 3 minute song to Wave on the emulated SID.

Running the command-line version without arguments will tell you what options it takes.

Comment: A guy called **Rolf R Bakke** has been doing [this SID oscilloscope 
thing with separated channels](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_J8tiAF6JEk&list=PLXhLeiiveJmNhFf5ShVwwXspGfgt-ww8c) on YouTube for a long time. He uses java SIDplay2 and a custom program to draw the waveforms.